# Regressing household income against index value of villages, where one village has one particular value only

Tags: regression

Suppose I am interested in knowing about the role of different dimension of institution on people's income. And I have taken 12 villages.
Households' income from these villages will be captured. And suppose we have 400 sample household.
Now the dimensions of institution of each village will be measured using an index.
Suppose the institution has three dimensions, 'variety', 'trust' and 'room for autonomous change'. For each village, each of the dimensions will have a particular value. Thus, each dimension will have 12 values as there are 12 villages.
In a regression, where I am interested to see the impact of these dimensions of institution on people's income, so these dimensions will be considered as independent variable. And income of households will be dependent.
Therefore, for the households of one particular vilage the values of each if the three independent variables (that is three dimensions) will be same but the income of the households of the respective village will be different.
Now i would like to know whether this type of regression is possible or not, if it is possible, then what type of regression I may run?

Comment: Any response from any source?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.